# Protected folders are empty after OneDrive sync

Tags: windows-10, sync, onedrive

We just updated Windows 10 Home Edition. Worked fine.
Then, out of the blue, this morning, it started a sync (didn't ask for it, didn't see any warning, at starting point or later).
When it ended, some folders had been "emptied".
This means that, when I open them, it shows nothing, and says "0 files".

Those particular folders were password protected by "ANVI folder locker".

I've checked the onedrive, and the folder is there, showing 0 files in it.

Search on the web say folders can't be deleted on the local HHD unless you choose to delete them from the drive. We haven't done that anyway. We haven't tried anything else yet, but only search for answers.

I wonder if ANVI deleted the files, even though this option seems very weird and isn't listed in its functionalities.

How can I locate the files on my HDD ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANVI folder locker is a scam run by a known Chinese hacker,
indicted by the U.S. Justice Department for a decade-long hacking spree that
targeted more than 100 high-tech and online gaming companies.

All it does is hide the folders. The password is only good for
viewing the files, not for access. This is evident from the fact that OneDrive
had no problems accessing these folders.

I suggest to uninstall this "product" and to run deep antivirus checks by more
than one antivirus products, such as Windows Defender and Malwarebytes.

For the missing files, all I can advice is to look in the Recycle Bin or in
your backups (that I hope you have).

For more details about ANVI, see the article
[Chinese Antivirus Firm Was Part of APT41 ‘Supply Chain’ Attack](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2020/09/chinese-antivirus-firm-was-part-of-apt41-supply-chain-attack/#more-53008).

Comment: Thanks. 1. I was able to locate the files ('hidden' was helpful tip from your answer) : they're still empty folders, but when I go one step at the time to OS_Win10 / Users / My_Name / Desktop (desktop was the original location of my protected folders), there are the files! 2. deleted the software (ran some security checks before/after = 0 threats). 3. OneDrive has created another "parallel system" where folders are still empty. 4. deleted OneDrive after full recovery and backup of files :) 5. can't UV - tick :/